# Trying to use col-xs Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-blade

Hi I'm trying to use the col-xs class for my elements so that they look in a mobile device. But unfortunately it doesn't look good. The following screenshot shows how it looks on my browser:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqyFT.png

However when I make my browser smaller I get this:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmOez.png

As you can see the first textfield, dropdownlist and button doesn't look good anymore. But I did use the col-xs class which should make it responsive (and look good) for mobile devices.

The search textfield and button however looks better, but that's maybe because I didn't use col-xs for that.

This is what I had tried:

```
{{Form::open(array('route'=>'user.store.work', 'method'=>'post'))}}
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-xs-4  col-xs-offset-3 " >{{Form::text('work_name', '',array('class' => 'form-control'))}}</div> 
                <div class="col-xs-2" >  
                    <select class="form-control"  name="worktypes" >
                        <option  selected value="order" >Offerte</option>
                        <option value="project">Project</option>
                        <option value="task">Taak</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                    {{Form::hidden('route', Request::path() )}}
                     {{--{{Form::hidden('id_user', Auth::user()->id )}}--}}

                {{Form::submit('Maken',  array('class' => 'btn btn-default col-xs-1 col-centered'))}}
               {{-- <div class="col-md-4 col-centered">{{Form::submit('Maken',  array('class' => 'btn btn-default', 'id' => 'work-submit'))}}</div> --}}
            </div>

{{Form::close()}}

{{ Form::open(array('url'=>url('user/search/order'), 'method'=>'post', 'class'=>'navbar-form navbar-right')) }} 

{{Form::hidden('route', Request::path() )}}

{{Form::token()}}

{{Form::text('keyword', 'Search', array('class'=>'form-control'))}}

{{Form::submit('Zoeken',  array('class' => 'btn btn-default'))}}

{{Form::close()}}
```

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 4):

You should only be using the `col-xs-*` classes if you are wanting to **force** the columns to display inline (side-by-side) on mobile devices (smaller screens).

In your case, it doesn't work when the screen is not wide enough because the content of the columns exceeds the width of the columns.

You should be using the `col-md-*` or `col-lg-*` classes instead which means the columns will collapse into a vertical format when the screen width becomes too small.

Examples of how the various classes work:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: The docs are very good for this.. take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: @Legin76 - Yup.  Essential to learning how all the bootstrap components work.